# How can attribute-level permissions be defined in Apache Shiro

Tags: shiro

From the [docs](http://shiro.apache.org/java-authorization-guide.html) I read that it's possible to define attribute-level permissions (as well as resource and instance levels)

> Attribute Level - The permission now specifies an attribute of an instance or resource. A user can edit the address on the IBM customer record.

How can these permissions be defined declaratively using the `<resource>:<action>:<instance>` format in which permissions in Shiro are usually defined? It would seem logical to be if it's possible to do something like `<resource>:<action>:<instance>:<attributename>` but I can't find docs anywhere discussing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html?

You can create the strings yourself from your own information. In our code we use custom realms to add the permissions programmatically like so:

```
public class OurAuthorizingReam extends AuthorizingRealm {
  ...
@Override
public AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    ... code to find permission infp

    SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    while (.. looping through permission info){
            info.addStringPermission(... the permission string constructed);
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: I did read the provided page several times, but nothing on attribute-permissions. Can you enlighten me a bit on what your custom code does? Do you have to write your own code to link stringpermissions to what attributes of a resource may be read/written to, or does Shiro provide some Middleware of some sort you can leverage?

Comment: The only thing shiro does is give you info whether a user has a certain permission (Subject.isPermitted()) and the way to add those permissions to the user. We have written our custom code around it. So we construct the permission strings from our own logic to do attribute checking.